# ¿Cómo agregarle el número de página a tcpdf?

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf

Amigos necesito su ayuda para ponerle la numeración de página a un reporte que está hecho en *tcpdf*

Este es el código:

```html
<?php
include("conexion.php");}
if(isset($_POST['crear'])){
  include("funciones.php"); 
  include('../tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

    $pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);

    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('autor');
    $pdf->SetTitle($_POST['reportes']);


    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->SetMargins(20, 20, 20, false);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 20);
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 10);
    $pdf->addPage();
    $content = '';
    $content .= '

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">

  <table class="table " border="1" cellpadding="5">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th colspan="4">
    
     <h3 class="text-center" align="center">reporte</h3>
      <p align="center">';

       $fecha_ac = actual_date(); 

        $content .= '
        '.$fecha_ac.'
      </p>
     </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   
   ';
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE codigo_registro LIKE '2%' ";
                $ejecutar = $conexion->query($sql);
                while($acts = $ejecutar->fetch_assoc()){
                    $content .= '
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" >'.$acts['codigo_registro'].'.'.utf8_encode($acts['nombre_registro']).'</td>
                    <td align="center">$ '.number_format($acts['cantidad1']-$acts['cantidad2'],2).'</td>
                    </tr> ';
                }
                
                $consulta = "SELECT SUM((cantidad1-cantidad2)) cantidadtotal FROM registros WHERE codigo_registro LIKE '2%' ";
                $ejecutar_consulta = $conexion->query($consulta);
                if($ejecutar_consulta->num_rows > 0){
                    while ($regs = $ejecutar_consulta->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $content .= '
                        <tr>
                        <td class="text-left"  colspan="3" ><strong>Total</strong></td>
                        <td align="center">$ '.number_format($regs['cantidadtotal'],2).'</td>
                        </tr>';
                    }
                }
$content .= '
  </tbody> 
  </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
';


  $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $content, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
    ob_end_clean();
    $pdf->output('Reporte.pdf', 'I');
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿viste la documentación oficial?  https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_003/

Comment: Si,pero quizá lo he hecho mal(no se muestra el numero de pagina),por eso pido su ayuda

Comment: Mira de nuevo el enlace que te puse, busca   public function Footer()  que es donde se imprime el pie de pagina con la numeración. En tu código no tienes nada parecido.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido Newtroyan, primero tienes que agregar la función footer:

```
// Page footer
 public function Footer() {
    // Position at 15 mm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Set font
    $this->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
}
```

Insertar un Font:

```
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', 
PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
```

Y luego especificar el margin:

```
 $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
```